# When I search in Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch send RESTAPI to original db?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search in Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch send RESTAPI to original db?

Or Elasticsearch have orginal data?

I find Elasticsearch have indexing data. But I can't certain Elasticsearch have original data.

Comment: What is original data? What APIs of ES are you using?

Comment: I didn't really try it because I only studied theory. I wonder the data retrieved from ES is imported whether microservice or ES itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch is a database itself, so if you want some external data source to be in Elasticsearch (e.g: SQL Database) you need to index the data into Elasticsearch first, and then search against that data.

So no, the REST Api will not query against the original DB but against the data you have in Elasticsearch.

You can read more about the process here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-getting-started-search-use-cases-db-logstash.html